# Poweredge R900 Perc 6/i

Tags: dell-perc

I have a Poweredge R900 server with Perc 6/i and a 3.5" x 5 backplane. I've been using (4) 600GB Dell SAS 15k drives in a RAID 10 configuration with no 5th drive. I just got around to adding a 5th drive to the server and I'm having problems getting the drive operational. I just want to add the 5th drive as JBOD (RAID 0) disk for backups. I've tried a 136GB Dell SAS 15K, a 2TB Western Digital RE4, and a 2TB Western Digital Black drive in the 5th slot with no luck. The lights on all three drives start out green but all three turn to a flashing amber during the boot process. If I go into the configuration settings (Ctrl-R) during the post the drives do not show up. My question is, what is most likely culprit? Is it the backplane, the Perc 6/i card, or the cables? Could it be that since I used RAID 10 I can't use the 5th slot?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kevin G

Answer (score 1):

First off, be sure that you're using a Dell branded drive. Many PERC card FW versions will "reject" non-Dell drives.
If you're running Windows with OMSA installed, the system event log should have some entries giving you a clue of what's going on. There's also the option of using OMSA to export the PERC controller log, though that may be difficult to read for some. 
If you test one of the existing 4 known-good drives in that slot (this might break your mirror and require a rebuild afterward), that could rule in/out the possibility of a bad backplane slot.